# Atmega8 microcontroller reading from bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, atmega

I want to read a byte sent by Bluetooth to the Atmega8 to process it. I found this function online to receive a byte

```
uint8_t receiveByte()
{
// Wait until a byte has been received
while((UCSRA&(1<<RXC)) == 0);

// Return received data
return UDR;
}
```

but it doesn't work by say turning a led on if 'a' was sent, so when I changed it and enabled port c to HIGH just before the while loop, and turned it low after it, but port c never gone low - which means this loop is infinite.

so my question is how to fix it or how can I read a byte from Bluetooth module
its atmega8-16pu and I configured it as follows:

```
/** define the cpu clock frequency*/
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
```

and fuse = 0xD9C4, from this site http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/

Comment: Have you enabled receive in the relevant UART config byte?

Comment: Okay I solved the issue! It was a problem in the baud rate and frequency. Thanks for your time.